# Can I reference an existing bash variable by joining variables together?

Tags: bash, variables

I've defined a variable say:

`bob_pants="fancy"`

and now I want to reference the contents of `$bobs_pants` by using another variable.

```
name="bob"
item="pants"
```

Can I do something like:

`echo "${name} has ${name}_${item} ${item}"`

I want the output for the above to be `"user bob has fancy pants"`
So far I've only succeeded in getting `"user bob has bob_pants pants"`

I guess I need some way for`${name}_${item}` to be seen as `${bob_pants}` but all the ways I tried to group the variables into one haven't worked.

Comment: So I tried both answers below and have chosen to implement ${!var} as it seems more elegant.
Using eval worked also.

Thank you both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bash`:

```
bob_pants="fancy"
name="bob"
item="pants"
var="${name}_${item}"
echo "${name} has ${!var} ${item}"
```

The `${!var}` notation evaluates to the variable named by `$var`.  However, you can't do:

```
echo "${name} has ${!${name}_${item}} ${item}"
```

Comment: I'll test this, but I don't think setting a new variable will be ideal in my case.  
will report back later.  
Thanks.

Comment: +1 for specifically stating "in bash"; For posix sh you can do something like: `eval \`echo \$${name}_${item}\` IIRC

Answer (score 0):

Check out `eval`:

```
$ x=bob  
$ y=pants  
$ echo $x\_$y  
bob_pants  
$ eval echo \$$x\_$y  
fancy
$
```

Comment: `eval` is evil! Especially when it's useless.

Comment: That looks like it might get me where I want to go.
I'll try it out later today and report back.

Comment: This suggestion works for me, but it's a little less elegant than the other suggestion I think.

Comment: @RonMcDonald Its also more portable than the other (bash only) version, and should work in any posix compliant shell.